# JMeter - Parallel plus sequential thread groups execution in the same test plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have my jmeter test plan like this,

```
Test Plan
  Thread Group1
  Thread Group2
  Thread Group3
  Thread Group4
```

and my Test Plan Configuration is set to run all thread groups in parallel

[image: Test Plan Configuration]

Here I want to execute **Thread Group1** and then **Thread Group2**
sequentially and same **Thread Group3** and then **Thread Group4**
But **Thread Group1** and **Thread Group3** parallel

So is there any way to group together **Thread Group1** with **Thread Group2** and **Thread Group3** with **Thread Group4** to run sequentially?

I know this very weird requirement but I have to suffer through it, appreciated your help in advance, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 3 options here:

1. **Use schedule** which would allow you to schedule 4 groups in a way that Group 1 and 3 run at the same time, and Groups 2 and 4 are scheduled to run after 1 and 3 complete.
2. **Run them using 2 JMeters**: in one JMeter you will have `Thread Group1` and `Thread Group2`, in the other - `Thread Group3` and `Thread Group4`. Each JMeter will be configured to run thread groups sequentially, but both will run in parallel, thus `Thread Group1` and `Thread Group3` will run in parallel
3. **Change test setup, so that there are 2 thread groups**:

   - Thread group A combines `Thread Group1` and `Thread Group2`
   - Thread group B combines `Thread Group3` and `Thread Group4`

   inside `Thread group A` and `Thread group B` you can use Loop controller to achieve specific number of iterations instead of Loop on Thread Group level. I.e.:

   ```
   Thread Group A
       Loop Controller [Count = same count as was used for Thread Group1]
           all samplers of Thread Group1
       Loop Controller [Count = same count as was used for Thread Group2]
           all samplers of Thread Group2
   Thread Group B
       Loop Controller [Count = same count as was used for Thread Group3]
           all samplers of Thread Group3
       Loop Controller [Count = same count as was used for Thread Group4]
           all samplers of Thread Group4
   ```